# How to add a column from several dataframes in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some csv files stored in a folder. I want to read each one of them and sum a specific column into a nem dataframe.
They all have the same index range and the same column name.
Here is what i have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\lsminervino\Desktop\MUN'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df2= pd.DataFrame(index=range(646))
for file in files:    
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="latin", sep=';')


    # new data frame with split value columns 
    new = df["Unnamed: 0"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)


    # making separate first name column from new data frame 
    df["IBGE"]= new[0] 

    # making separate last name column from new data frame 
    df["Cidade"]= new[1]

    # Dropping old Name columns 
    df.drop(columns =["Unnamed: 0"], inplace = True) 

    df = df.set_index('Cidade')

    df2 = df['Total']

df2.head()

Out:
Cidade
 Adamantina          0
 Adolfo              0
 Aguaí               0
 Águas da Prata      0
 Águas de Lindóia    0
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

What i expected is a sum (which i couldn't make to code without a error) of every column with the name 'Total' of every file in the folder in a new dataframe.

Here is a sample of one of the .csv files:

```
                  Unnamed: 0  Total  Cadastro  Sem Registro Civil
0        3500105 - Adamantina   17.0      17.0                   0
1            3500204 - Adolfo    3.0       3.0                   0
2             3500303 - Aguaí   14.0      14.0                   0
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata    2.0       2.0                   0
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia    0.0       0.0                   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `concat` and `groupby` . Does this work for you :

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\lsminervino\Desktop\MUN'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
total_df = []
for file in files:    
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="latin", sep=';')


    # new data frame with split value columns 
    new = df["Unnamed: 0"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)


    # making separate first name column from new data frame 
    df["IBGE"]= new[0] 

    # making separate last name column from new data frame 
    df["Cidade"]= new[1]

    # Dropping old Name columns 
    df.drop(columns =["Unnamed: 0"], inplace = True) 

    total_df.append(df['Total'])

df_final = pd.concat(total_df).groupby(by='Cidade').sum()
```

Comment: Okay, sorry about that..  What did not work ? Feel free to edit my answer or leave a comment here with the edits

Comment: Your code didn't quit work but helped me work out a solution:

`total_df = []
for file in files:    
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="latin", sep=';')
   

    new = df["Unnamed: 0"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)

    
    df["IBGE"]= new[0] 

    df["Cidade"]= new[1]

    df.drop(columns =["Unnamed: 0"], inplace = True) 
    df = df.set_index('Cidade')
    df2 = df['Total']

    total_df.append(df2)
df_final = pd.concat(total_df).groupby(by='Cidade').sum()`

Comment: It raised a problem : KeyError: 'Cidade'
I think setting the index solved that as the code above shows
tks